# Writing to simulator log file without writing to terminal

Tags: system-verilog

I would like to write to the simulator log file without writing to the terminal. I'm guessing it's not possible to do this from SystemVerilog code, but is it possible using the VPI?

I looked at the `vpi_mcd_printf` method. It states that channel 1 represents the output channel of the tool **and** the log file. Is there a way to only write to the log file?

---

The background for this question is that I would like to implement colors for error/warning messages. Terminals can take escape characters, which control the color that gets displayed. If I just write such escape characters using a `$display` call, I'll get the desired behavior in the terminal, but the log file will contain these escape characters verbatim. They will also be present when the tool is started in GUI mode, where messages aren't printed in the terminal, but in the tool's console.

I can write to the terminal using a regular `printf` from C code, but there's still the issue of writing to the log file.

Comment: writing to terminal and to log requires two different file descriptors. therefore in 'c' you need to printf twice. same in verilog.  *vpi_mcd_printf* is a hack that just allows to printf into multiple descriptors at the same time. None of them catch run-time messages from simulation kernel. You might be able to do that in 'c' with *freopen()* or whatever to redirect stdout to a different place(s). It might be easier just to 'pipe' the output through a colorizer or do a post-processin of the log.

Answer (score 1):

Your question starts off asking how suppress printing to the terminal. But your background to your question suggest you want the option to separately control the format to both.

## Terminal/stdout suppression:

Your simulators might have a built in in command line option; ex `-noprint`, `-nostdout`, or `-quiet`. Check the manual for your specific simulator.

For Linux based simulation you can always pipe the standard output to `/dev/null`

### If using UVM:

Use the plusarg `+uvm_set_action=*,_ALL_,UVM_INFO,UVM_LOG +uvm_set_action=*,_ALL_,UVM_WARNING,UVM_LOG` so info and warning messages will only go to a log file; error and fatal will still go to standard out and log.

To get all UVM messages to go only to the logs files you could add something like the following to the top of your base test's build_phase:

```
set_report_severity_action_hier(UVM_INFO,    UVM_LOG);
set_report_severity_action_hier(UVM_WARNING, UVM_LOG);
set_report_severity_action_hier(UVM_ERROR,   UVM_LOG | UVM_COUNT);
set_report_severity_action_hier(UVM_FATAL,   UVM_LOG | UVM_EXIT);
```

Both allow ways to mix and match with controls on component, ID, and severity.

Reference guild for UVM messaging:
http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2014AUS_UVM_Messages.pdf

## Fine tone control:

If you really need to terminal and log output to differ (ex color formatting, making log in XML format, etc.), then you will need to avoid using `$display` and instead use your own VPI or DPI functions. To the best of my knowledge, you cannot override the `$display` system function.

As stated in your background statement, you can write terminal using a regular `printf` from C code. To write exclusivly to the log file, you can use `$fdisplay`/`$fwrite` or your own VPI/DPI code to target output file. Probably cannot be the default log file.

Your simulator might have a command to disable writing to the default log file if file management is an issue.

### UVM Expert!!!

You need create your own report_server (extended form `uvm_report_server`) and override the `execute_report_message` and `compose_report_message`. This might require you to write your own VPI or DPI functions.

uvm_report_server XML example: http://www.verilab.com/files/SNUG_Applications_of_custom_UVM_report_servers.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough response. I'm explicitly interested in writing to the default log file, because I would like to have something that is as close to "regular" operation as possible. I'm also pretty sure it's not possible, unfortunately, because there's no way to split the up the tools "default output" and its "default log file".